# Angular 2; Assign Method to EventEmitter using ViewChild in Typescript instead of in HTML?

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, how can I assign an EventEmitter to its method handler using the ViewChild in Typescript?

Handling Events from EventEmitter using HTML:

**my.component.html**

```
<some-component [someProperty]="myProperty" (onSomeEvent)="myMethod($event)></some-component>
```

**my.component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {
    public myProperty: string;
    ...
    public myMethod(event: any) {
        ... //handle event
    }
    ...
}
```

How I'd prefer to handle events (in Typescript):

**my.component.html**

```
<some-component #someComponent></some-component>
```

**my.component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild('someComponent') someComponent: SomeComponent;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.someComponent.someProperty = myProperty;
        this.someComponent.onSomeEvent = ? <-- How do I assign EventEmitter?
    }
    public myProperty: string;
    ...
    public myMethod(event: any) {
        ... //handle event
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured this out a month later when I came across the problem again and serendipitously rediscovered my own question in the search.

Because Angular's EventEmitters utilize observables, under the hood they are just subscribing to the Observable.  You can do it too if you want to assign the handler in the component typescript.

From my example above:

```
export class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild('someComponent') someComponent: SomeComponent;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.someComponent.someProperty = myProperty;
        this.someComponent.onSomeEvent.subscribe(event => this.myMethod(event));
    }
    public myProperty: string;
    ...
    public myMethod(event: any) {
        ... //handle event
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, now i see the difference between emit on HTML or on Typescript.